# everyone, i have changed my code now i'm making linked list using functions it is successfully build but not printing anything, plz tell my mistake

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
};
class LinkedList{
    Node *head;
    public:
        //Node *head;
        LinkedList(){
            head=NULL;
        }
        void addAtTail(int);
        void print();
};
void LinkedList::addAtTail(int val){
    Node *nodeToAdd=new Node();
    nodeToAdd->data=val;
    if(head==NULL){
        head=nodeToAdd;
    }
    else{
        Node *temp=head;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp->next=nodeToAdd;
    }
}
void LinkedList::print(){
    Node *temp=head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL){
        cout<<temp->data;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    LinkedList ll;
    ll.addAtTail(10);
    ll.addAtTail(20);
    ll.addAtTail(30);
    ll.print();
    cout<<"Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

i have tried to make linked list by splitting it in functions. It is build successfully but not printing anything can anyone tell me my mistake. Firstly in this post i tried to delete a node which was not in functions now i have another doubt a snow i'm making linked list using functions .

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Unless you are actually compiling as both or asking for a comparison or differences in your situation, you should generally only include the language tag that applies.

Comment: I'm the guy who just drops a comment complaining about C-style linked lists being taught in C++. This implementation is worse than that by requiring the menu to be a part of the linked list implementation. If you are required to have the menu, at least make each choice call the corresponding linked list function, and don't weld the menu and linked list together.

Comment: The only way to "delete" a node is to use the `delete` keyword. Anything allocated with `new` should have a corresponding `delete`. Your idea of "deleting" without using the keyword is leaking memory and incorrect.

Comment: its a tiny detail, but imho its better to show the code that does have the problem you describe, ie `//delete curNode->next;` -> `delete curNode->next;`. Any single character we have to change on your code to reproduce the issue is a source of confusion and misunderstanding

Comment: btw garbage-collection refers to a mechanism that is not built in C++ because C++ has other means to automatically manage memory and they are very different from garbage collection (removed the tag)

Comment: After `delete curNode->next;` you must not access `curNode->next->next`. Use something like `auto tmp = curNode->next;` `curNode->next=curNode->next->next;` `delete tmp;`

Comment: Your actual issue seems to be that you delete a node, then try to de-reference the just-deleted node. You need a temporary pointer that will point to the node you want to delete, then change your linking to skip the deleted node, and finally delete the node in question using the temporary pointer. Draw the steps out on a piece of paper. It's the single best way to figure out how linked list code should go.

Comment: If you change your question in such big way (by your edit), we all lose interest in answering, because it makes any answers look stupid.

Answer (score 0):

For starters your code does not distinguish the position equal to 0 and the position equal to 1 because for the both positions this while loop

```
               while(i<pos-1){
                curNode=curNode->next;
                i++;
                }
```

will not be executed.

Also within the loop you are not checking whether `curNode` becomes equal to a null pointer.

This statement

```
curNode->next=curNode->next->next;
```

also can invoke undefined behavior in case when `curNode->next` is a null pointer.

And the removed from the list node should be deleted using the operator delete. Otherwise there will be a memory leak.

You could rewrite this code snippet for example the following way

```
           else{
               cout<<"Enter Position - ";
               cin>>pos;
               
               if ( pos < 0 )
               {
                   std::cout << "Invalid position.\n";
               }
               else
               {
                   Node **curNode = &head;
                   
                   while ( *curNode && pos-- )
                   {
                       curNode = &( *curNode )->next;
                   }

                   if ( *curNode == nullptr )
                   {
                       std::cout << "Invalid position.\n";
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       Node *tmp = *curNode;
                       *curNode = ( *curNode )->next;
                       delete tmp;
                   }
               }

               break;
           }
```

Pay attention to that other parts of the program that deal with positions also can invoke undefined behavior or produce a memory leak and should be rewritten.

Also it would be much better if you will split your program into separate functions.

Comment: can you help me with the proper changes in code ?

Comment: Hi, as you said me to spit my code in functions i have tried it but it is not printing anything can you help me, please?

Comment: @NamanVerma {at attention to that it is a bad idea to change the original code in the question such a cardinal way. This will only confuse readers of the question and answers. You shall restore the original code. Then you should close the current question selection the best answer and after that ask a new question with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

while inserting the node, you are making temp=NULL and then NULL->next=nodeToAdd which would give an error

so make the while condition as while(temp->next!=NULL)

Incase of printing you are not going till the last node, for this change the while condition to while(temp!=NULL)

```
void LinkedList::addAtTail(int val){
    Node *nodeToAdd=new Node();
    nodeToAdd->data=val;
    if(head==NULL){
        head=nodeToAdd;
    }
    else{
        Node *temp=head;
        while(**temp->next!=NULL**){
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp->next=nodeToAdd;
    }
}
void LinkedList::print(){
    Node *temp=head;
    while(**temp!=NULL**){
        cout<<temp->data;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```